# How to pack and transport only the delta of a container?

Tags: docker, containers, podman

I have the following scenario:

A docker or podman container is setup ready and deployed to several production instances, that are NOT connected to the internet.

A new release has been developed, that needs only a new package, like a python module of a few kilobytes in size.

The new package is installed on dev container, and the dockerfile has been updated to also load the latest module (just for documentation, because the target system cannot reach docker.io).

We have packed the new container release, which is more than a Gigabyte in size. And could transport the new container to the target environments.

My question is: is there a way, to pack, create and transport only a delta of the container compared to the previously deployed version?

podman version 3.4.7

```
echo "\
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y mupdf-tools python3-dev

USER user
RUN pip -V
RUN pip install fitz==0.0.1.dev2
RUN pip install PyMuPDF==1.20.2
RUN pip install seaborn
RUN pip install openpyxl==3.0.10
RUN pip install flask==2.1.3
" > sciPyDockerfile
podman build --tag python_runner -f ./sciPyDockerfile
```

```
sudo podman save -o python_runner.tar python_runner
gzip python_runner.tar
```

The result is a file

```
1.1G Nov 28 15:27 python_runner.tar.gz
```

Is there any way to pack the delta only?

Comment: I have seen the diff command, but I cannot create a transportable format from it, yet.

`podman diff python_runner | less`

Comment: If Podman works like standard Docker here, a `save` command _always_ includes the entire images, including base image layers that might be available on Docker Hub.  In most cases you should prefer pushing to a registry instead, and that will be able to push and pull only changed layers.